# AWK Filter and then trim output

Tags: awk

I am looking to trim the output below

```
curl -s -L https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/mac/workspace-app-for-mac-latest.html#ctx-dl-eula-external | awk '/<p>Version:&nbsp;/ {print $1}'
```

Current Output: `<p>Version:&nbsp;20.08.0.3`

Desired Output: 20.08.0.3

Comment: We need to see a sample of the text that's being input to awk to be able to help you write an awk script to parse that text. We don't need to see the command you'd run to generate such text (i.e. `curl...`)

Comment: Hi if you scroll over it shows the awk command.

Comment: @whatskendoing Ed Morton was not talking about the awk command, he was pointing out that showing the curl is not as useful as showing that actual data you are piping to awk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only.

```
your_command | awk '
match($0,/<p>Version:&nbsp;([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/.*;/,"",val)
  print val
  val=""
}'
```

Comment: This work perfect if I cut and paste but if I try to make that one line it errors out

Comment: @whatskendoing, I didn't get it could you please elaborate on your error I could fix it then, cheers.

Comment: if I do command | match($0,/<p>Version:&nbsp;([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)sub(/.*;/,"",val) print val val=""}' that doesn't work

Comment: @whatskendoing, you need to put your `curl_command | awk.....` command like that, could you please do let me know if you have done the same?

Comment: @whatskendoing, like this `your_curl_command | awk 'match($0,/<p>Version:&nbsp;([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/.*;/,"",val);print val;val=""}'`

Answer (score 0):

```sh
curl -s -L https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/mac/workspace-app-for-mac-latest.html#ctx-dl-eula-external | awk '{print substr($1,index($1,";")+1)}'
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the snippet, but the output that command gives is: 20.08.0.3 (2008)<br>

Comment: @whatskendoing it always helps to have a representative data sample. I've modified the "suggestion".